# Transforming multiple lists into one DataFrame

Tags: pandas, list, tuples, transform

I'm looking for a convenient and simple method to combine three tuples of lists into a Dataframe (?) with a total of six columns.

```
list1 = [('word1', 0.6037212610244751), ('word2', 0.5418980717658997),('word3', 0.5389199256896973), ('word4', 0.51054847240448), ('word5', 0.49834704399108887)]

list2 = [('word6', 0.6037212610244751), ('word7', 0.5418980717658997),('word8', 0.5389199256896973), ('word9', 0.51054847240448), ('word10', 0.49834704399108887)]

list3 =[('word11', 0.6037212610244751), ('word12', 0.5418980717658997),('word13', 0.5389199256896973), ('word14', 0.51054847240448), ('word15', 0.49834704399108887)]
```

For each of the two columns of a list, I want to use "Word" and "Value" as a header.

**My desired output:**

```
Word   Score   Word   Score   Word   Score
word1  0.603   word6  0.603   word11 0.603
...
word5  0.498   ...
```

**So far, I tried:**

```
from pandas import DataFrame
data = [list1,list2,list3]
DataFrame.from_records(data, columns = ['Word','Score','Word','Score','Word'])

    Word    Score   Word    Score   Word
0   (word1, 0.6037212610244751) (word2, 0.5418980717658997) (word3, 0.5389199256896973) (word4, 0.51054847240448)   (word5, 0.49834704399108887)
1   (word6, 0.6037212610244751) (word7, 0.5418980717658997) (word8, 0.5389199256896973) (word9, 0.51054847240448)   (word10, 0.49834704399108887)
2   (word11, 0.6037212610244751)    (word12, 0.5418980717658997)    (word13, 0.5389199256896973)    (word14, 0.51054847240448)  (word15, 0.49834704399108887)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) on `axis=1`:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(list1,columns=['word','values']),pd.DataFrame(list2,columns=['word','values']),pd.DataFrame(list3,columns=['word','values'])],axis=1)

    word    values    word    values    word    values
0  word1  0.603721   word6  0.603721  word11  0.603721
1  word2  0.541898   word7  0.541898  word12  0.541898
2  word3  0.538920   word8  0.538920  word13  0.538920
3  word4  0.510548   word9  0.510548  word14  0.510548
4  word5  0.498347  word10  0.498347  word15  0.498347
```